# How do I select a specified row in a linq list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq list.  I would like to select a certain row.  Do I have to do a foreach to loop thru the rows to get to the specified row, or is there another way.

What I dont want...

**EDIT**

```
specifiedRow = 13;
```

**-**

```
var linqList = from a in random.List
               where (a.id == idNum)
               select new {a.id, a.name, a.address};
int counter = 0;
foreach (var item in linqList) {
    if(counter == specifiedRow) {
        //do stuff
    }   
}
```

What I would like...

```
var linqList = from a in random.List
               where (a.id == idNum)
               //row is specified row in linqList
               select new {a.id, a.name, a.address};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
linqList.Skip(specifiedRow -1).FirstOrDefault()
```

That should give you the item you want, or `null` if there weren't enough rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the row number that you're after then you can use the Skip() method

Eg to get the 6th row:

```
var linqList = from a in random.List
           where (a.id == idNum)
           Skip(5)
           select new {a.id, a.name, a.address};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
random.List.Where(a => a.id == idNum).Select(a => new {a.id, a.name, a.address}).ElementAt(counter);
```

Comment: I like this approach because it's the most explicit.